# I've facing problem in android dependecy injection

Tags: android

What is best module in Android for dependency handling?

1. Dragger
2. Hilt

I'm little bit confused

Comment: Hilt is an extension of Dagger which is created specially for android .. So

Comment: hilt is best for di in android

Answer (score -1):

Hilt is built on top of the Dagger dependency injection library, providing a standard way to incorporate Dagger into an Android application.

Because the Android operating system instantiates many of its own framework classes, using Dagger in an Android app requires you to write a substantial amount of boilerplate. Hilt reduces the boilerplate code that is involved in using Dagger in an Android application. Hilt automatically generates and provides the following:

- **Components for integrating Android framework classes** with Dagger that you would otherwise need to create by hand.
- **Scope annotations** to use with the components that Hilt generates automatically.
- **Predefined bindings** to represent Android classes such as `Application` or `Activity`.
- **Predefined qualifiers** to represent `@ApplicationContext` and `@ActivityContext`.

Dagger and Hilt code can coexist in the same codebase. However, in most cases it is best to use Hilt to manage all of your usage of Dagger on Android.